# Check for data in database before delete

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have these 2 forms (Add.aspx) "CalculationParameters" and "CalculationParametersValues". I also have 2 forms (Delete.aspx). These two forms are related. If there is no CalculationParameter, then you cannot add CalculationParametersValues. Now my problem is... when I delete a CalculationParameter, I want to check first if the CalculationParammeter has any CalculationParametersValues. I need to do this using this "`=>`" which is new to me, but I can't get the hang of it.
I get the values from database from here : `"Factory.Definitions.CalculationParameters.List()"` and `"Factory.Definitions.CalculationParametersValues.List()"`.

It should be something like this (I think):

```
Factory.Definitions.CalculationParameters.List(item => (item.Id == <NOW here is where I should equal that Id with "CalculationParameterId">)
```

Help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know which `CalculationParameter` is deleting and it's `Id` the solution will be:

```
var paramValues = Factory.Definitions.CalculationParametersValues.Where(p => p.Id == calculationParameter.Id);
```

Suggest reading [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx). It is short and clear with nice examples for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add New Item
If (Factory.Definitions.CalculationParameters.List().Where(item => item.ID == NewItem.ID).Count == 0)
{
// Add new item to list
Factory.Definitions.CalculationParametersValues.List().Add(NewItem);
}

// Delete item
If (Factory.Definitions.CalculationParametersValues.List().Where(item => item.ID == DeleteItem.ID).Count == 0)
{
// No record in Values list ... Do something here
}
else
{
// Some records in Values list .. Do something here
}
```